# Why is my user unauthorized to execute a graphql mutation with the aws-amplify api and cognito authentication?

Tags: authorization, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, http-status-code-401

I have a page on my Vuejs site that allows a user to update their profile details including, first name, last name, email address and phone number. When the user submits a form, there is a call to the aws-amplify api's endpoint graphqlOperation().

```
API.graphql(graphqlOperation(updateUser, { input: newUserDetails }))
```

where the updateUser mutation is defined as follows...

```
export const updateUser = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation UpdateUser(
    $input: UpdateUserInput!
    $condition: ModelUserConditionInput
  ) {
    updateUser(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      userName
      firstName
      lastName
      email
      phoneNumber
      userDetails
      userNotes
      role
      _version
      _deleted
      _lastChangedAt
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
```

and newUserDetails is as follows...

```
 const newUserDetails = {
    id: 17347,
    firstName: 'Sally',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    email: 'Sallysmith@gmail.com',
    phone: '+19827772222',
  }
```

I am using AWS Amplify/Cognito for authentication.

Why does submitting this form result in a 401 unauthorized error?

If this error is due to a mistake in my Cognito user group permissions, please link documentation explaining how to allow this user group to call this mutation function.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple auth modes configured then you need to specify Cognito:

```
const newArtist = await API.graphql({
      query: updateUser,
      variables: {input: user},
      authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS'
    });
```